# What happened to the "Run as different user" for Office 2013, Word, Excel no longer show it?

Tags: windows-7, ms-office, runas

When I shift + right click the shortcut for Word 2013, the "Run as different user" is not available. It works for non Office 2013 shortcuts.

How can I re-enable this for Office 2013 products?

Answer (score 1):

Open Windows Explorer, and type 'winword' into the top-right Search box.
Wait for the results to come back.
Shift+rightclick the 'WINWORD' entry, and select 'Run as different user'.